# Missing provisioning profile when building archive on Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building archive first time in Xcode 13 beta/Big Sur for a React Native app and have the above error of `your-app requires provisioning profile` under Target->project->Signing & Capabilities.

[image]

It is `None` for `Provisioning Profile` and there is option of `download` besides to `None`. However changing to `download` does not have any profile available to download.

The account in Xcode is linked to a personal developer team with paid developer account. It is `automatic` under project->Signing->Provisioning Profile. The build target is `Any IOS devices` but I don't have any iOS device attached to the app (don't have one). The intention of archive is to distribute a test version on a 3rd party distribution channel.

Comment: "It is automatic" No it isn't. Check the Automatically Manage Signing checkbox.

Comment: Checking the box of "Automatically Manage Signing" will get 2 errors: Failed to create provisioning profile and No profiles for xxxx were found.

Comment: I can't explain that, but in a worst case scenario you could just go to the member center and make a profile.

Comment: Hi `Matt`, I created.a provisioning profile under dev account for IOS platform and type of App Store, linked with the App ID. But the error is the same as checking automatic. Do I have to use a IOS device to generate a provisioning profile? many thanks.

Comment: You've made the wrong kind of provisioning profile. You're not trying submit to the App Store, you're trying to archive. For that, you need a _development_ profile (not a distribution profile). — I'm starting to understand the problem, I think! You've never actually even run this app on a device, have you? Because (as you've said) you don't _have_ a device. And therefore you've never registered a device at the member center. Is that right?